SAP UI5 Chrome Extension Build Error with Plasmo
I'm building a Chrome extension with Plasmo (React). I would like to use SAP UI5 as the UI framework.
However, I get a build error. It just tells me that it can't load some files:

Failed to resolve '@ui5/webcomponents-fiori/dist/types/IllustrationMessageSize.js' from './node_modules/.pnpm/@ui5+webcomponents-react@1.29.8_@types+react-dom@18.2.18_@types+react@18.2.48_@ui5+webcompone_igleod7ys5qvbjjmpnskqdhsu4/node_modules/@ui5/webcomponents-react/dist/enums/IllustrationMessageSize.js'
Cannot load file './dist/types/IllustrationMessageSize.js' from module '@ui5/webcomponents-fiori'

Do I have to release something specific in the manifest.json, or do I have to pay attention to something else? So far, I have only installed and initialised the framework.
content.tsx:
import { Button, ThemeProvider } from "@ui5/webcomponents-react"
import type { PlasmoGetInlineAnchor } from "plasmo"

import "@ui5/webcomponents/dist/Assets"
import "@ui5/webcomponents-fiori/dist/Assets"
import "@ui5/webcomponents-react/dist/Assets"

export const config = {
  matches: ["https://*.hana.ondemand.com/*"]
}

export const getInlineAnchor: PlasmoGetInlineAnchor = () =>
  document.querySelector("#shell--navigationList")

const PlasmoInline = () => {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider>
      <Button onClick={() => alert("Hello World!")}>Hello world!</Button>
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}

export default PlasmoInline

manifest.json:
"host_permissions": [
      "https://*/*"
],
"permissions": [
      "tabs",
      "activeTab",
      "storage",
      "scripting"
]

